# Graph of this integral. Is it a half circle or quarter circle?

Tags: calculus

I'm reading this text:

[image]

$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{1 - x^2} \cdot dx$$

Why isn't the above integral the right half of a circle? Why did they show the equation of $y^2$? Was the point of that just to show that it's a circle? But that just confuses people because they don't really explain why it's just 1 quarter of a circle. I guess y cannot be negative? But $y$ can be negative in the $y^2$ equation.

Comment: Because $\sqrt{1-x^2} \ge 0$ for all real $x$ where it is defined.

Comment: And we don't have the left side of the circle because the integral is from 0 to 1 right? Then why did they bring up the parts about y^2? Why did they square both sides? When they do that, they change the answer right? Now y can be negative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is asking you to evaluate the integral
$$\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
by interpreting this integral as an area.  In order to do this, we need to understand the shape of the region being enclosed.  To do this, we might reason as follows:

1. Since the limits of the integral are $0$ and $1$, the area we are interested lives on the interval $[0,1]$.  That is the area pictured here:

   [image]
2. Next, the integral is the area enclosed between the curve $y = \sqrt{1+x^2}$ and the $x$-axis.  Note that the square root function is, by definition, the *positive* square root.  This implies that when $\sqrt{x}$ is defined, it is nonnegative.  In other words, the curve that bounds the region of interest, i.e. $y = \sqrt{1-x^2}$, lives *only* above the $x$-axis.  It doesn't extend below the $x$-axis at all.  Hence we are interested in the region that is above the $x$-axis and below the curve.
3. Finally, using a graphing utility, this *looks like* a semicircle above the $x$-axis:

   [image]

   If we are being careful (as we ought to be), we should check this:  recall that that a circle centered at the point $(h,k)$ with radius $r$ is described by the equation
   $$ (x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = r^2. $$
   Since the region that we are interested in looks like a semicircle of radius 1 centered at the origin, this should be the region bounded by the curve
   $$ x^2 + y^2 = 1. $$
   Solving for $y$, we get
   $$ y^2 = 1-x^2
   \implies y = \pm \sqrt{1-x^2}.$$
   We are interested in the region *above* the $x$-axis and *below* the line $y = \sqrt{1-x^2}$.  The above argument shows that this upper bound is a semicircle.  Yay!

Intersecting the blue and red regions above, we get the quarter circle, which has area $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! BTW there is a typo in the line below the first image. it should be: $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Answer (score 3):

If $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ then $y = \pm \sqrt{1-x^2}.$ You've got only the "plus" part; not the "minus" part.

Comment: why only the plus part?

Comment: @Jwan622 Convention. That way the square root does not ambiguously point to two different values. If you need to refer to both square roots, you can use the $\pm$ symbol.

Comment: Why does the text give us the equation for $y^2$

Comment: Jwan622 because the given curve is a part of that. But yes it's not true that both curves are same.

Comment: @Jwan622 : You  wrote $\sqrt{1-x^2}.$ For the area below one graph and above another, you have something like $\displaystyle\int_a^b (g(x)-f(x))\,dx.$ In this case $g(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $f(x) = -\sqrt{1-x^2},$ so $g(x)-f(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2} - \big( -\sqrt{1-x^2}\, \big) = 2\sqrt{1-x^2}. \qquad$

Answer (score 2):

Remember that $\sqrt{1-x^2} \geq 0$ for all $x$ because $\sqrt{x} \geq 0$ for all $x$.

Perhaps you are thinking of the following derivation:

$$\begin{align}x^2+y^2&=1 \\
y^2&=1-x^2\\
y&=\sqrt{1-x^2}\\
\end{align}$$

But remember that $x^2+y^2=1$ is *an implicit curve*, not a function. For us to end up with a function we restrict $\sqrt{x}$ to principal square roots. In reality, to get 'both quarters', you need:

$$y=\pm \sqrt{1-x^2}$$